# Why VS does imul rax,rax,0 instead of simple move?

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit

I was looking at the assembly Visual Studio generated for this simple x64 program:

```
struct Point {
    int a, b;

    Point() {
        a = 0; b = 1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Point arr[3];
    arr[0].b = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

And when it meets *arr[0].b = 2*, it generates this:

```
mov eax, 8
imul rax, rax, 0
mov dword ptr [rbp+rax+4],2
```

Why does it do *imul rax, rax, 0* instead of a simple *mov rax, 0*, or even *xor rax, rax*? How is imul more efficient, if at all?

Comment: Try compiling with optimization switches.

Comment: I've tried with no optimization and with /02, but it still did imul rax,rax,0. With full optimization I couldn't even get it to actually write anything to arr[0], it was storing everything as temporary variable or something like that

Comment: Your VS isn't the same as mine it seems.  This generates no code at all with /O2 as expected.  Rejiggering the code so the optimizer cannot remove the assignment produces mov  dword ptr [rsp+24h],2 as expected.  imul is only ever generated in an unoptimized build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kamac

The reason is because the assembly is calculating the offset of both the `Point` object in the array, which happens to be on the stack, as well as the offset to the variable `b`.

Intel documentation for `imul` with three (3) operands state:

> **Three-operand form** — This form requires a destination operand (the
>   first operand) and two source operands (the second and the third
>   operands). Here, the first source operand (which can be a
>   general-purpose register or a memory location) is multiplied by the
>   second source operand (an immediate value). The intermediate product
>   (twice the size of the first source operand) is truncated and stored
>   in the destination operand (a general-purpose register).

In your case it is calculating the offset of the object in the array which results in addressing the first (zeroth) `Point` location on the stack. Having that resolved it is then adding the offset for `.b` which is the `+4`. So broken down:

```
mov  eax,8                   ; prepare to offset into the Point array
imul rax, rax, 0             ; Calculate which Point object is being referred to
mov  dword ptr [rbp+rax+4],2 ; Add the offset to b and move value 2 in
```

instruction. All of which resolves to `arr[0].b = 2`.

I take it you did not compile with aggressive optimization. When going with a straight compile (no optimization, debug on, etc.) the compiler is not making any assumptions with respects to addressing.

**Comparison to clang**

On OS X (El Capitan) with `clang 3.9.0` and no optimization flags, once the `Point` objects are instantiated in the array, the assignment of `.b = 2` is simply:

```
mov dword ptr [rbp - 44], 2
```

In this case, `clang` is pretty smart about the offsets and resolves addressing during the default optimization.

Comment: Doesn't explain why the compiler doesn't just `mov dword ptr [rbp+4], 2` instead.

Comment: @EOF Imagine it was `arr[10].b`. It needs to multiply the size of `Point` by `10` to get the offset to the array element.

Comment: @EOF then it would be `imul rax, rax, 10`

Comment: @Barmar: If it was `arr[10].b`, that would be undefined behavior for out-of-bounds access. Don't try to get smart with me, you're no good at it.

Comment: @EOF The point is that it's just naively putting the index into the `imul` instruction. If the code was optimized it would probably do better.